# Docker compose error: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":9000"

Tags: docker, uwsgi

When I run my Docker-based application with `docker-deploy docker-compose-deploy.yml up` I have this error in my terminal:

```
no host in upstream ":9000" in /etc/nginx/co
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
```

My `docker-compose-deploy.yml` contains:

```sh
FROM  nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine
LABEL maintainer="londonappdeveloper.com"

COPY ./default.conf.tpl /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
COPY ./run.sh /run.sh

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000
ENV AP_HOST=app
ENV APP_PORT=9000

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static && \
    chmod 755 /vol/static && \
    touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chmod +x /run.sh

VOLUME /vol/static

USER nginx

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

and in my `default.conf.tpl`:

```
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;
    }
}
```

Comment: the file should be suffixed with .template. Not .tpl.

Comment: you mean, my file default.conf.tpl change of default.conf.template? I try to do this and no change in my terminal

Comment: Looks like you are not using the template mechanism build into the image. You probably do some custom stuff in run.sh. I that case you need to show your run.sh. I would put my template according to this script and remove the CMD. https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/entrypoint/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

Comment: In the Dockerfile you have `AP_HOST` with only one `P`; is this the cause of the problem?  You say you have a `docker-compose.deploy.yml` file but actually included a Dockerfile; is there anything important in the Compose setup (environment-variable settings, volume mounts that override what's in the Dockerfile)?

Comment: Thank you for your response "The Fool" and "David Maze", It's work with the APP_HOST. I can continuous my tutorial.